# Mockito/PowerMock: Mock static field of class when static initialization has been suppressed

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I am trying to write a unit test for a method within a class, RPCProxy. This file contains some static initialization blocks for creating things related to the production environment, and for the purposes of the tests, and specifically the methods I'm trying to test, they don't make use of these production related things. Therefore, I have suppressed static initialization (without it errors are thrown because certain classes and objects cannot be found). The issue I am running into is that the class I am trying to write tests for also contains many static variables that are now not being created. The methods I am testing assume that these objects exist and, as such, when the method runs and it tries to call a method on one of these objects a NullPointerException gets thrown.

What I want to know how to do is somehow mock these objects and insert them into the class somehow, so that the method uses my version, instead of the version it expects to exist which actually doesn't.

For some context on what I am testing: I am trying to gets the static method RPCProxy.getInstance. This method calls a private static method called create, which returns a Proxy object. I have mocked the Proxy object, and mocked the create method to return the mocked proxy object. The only problem is that the newInstance method tries to use some of the earlier mentioned objects that do not exist.

```
Proxy mockProxy = Mockito.mock(Proxy.class);

PowerMockito.spy(RPCProxy.class);

PowerMockito.doReturn(mockProxy).when(RPCProxy.class, "create", Mockito.any(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString());

assertSame(mockProxy, RPCProxy.getInstance("test12345"));
```